# Why this code block showing stack smashing detection?

Tags: c

So I am not able run the code which I have attached below. The program is about multiplication of 2 matrices. I am getting stack smashing detection. I am new to this problem. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#define R1 3
#define C1 4
#define R2 C1
#define C2 2
void main()
{
        int i,j,k,mat1[R1][C1],mat2[R2][C2],mat3[R1][C2];
        printf("Enter 1st matrix(%dX%d) :",R1,C1);
        for(i=0;i<R1;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<C1;j++)
                {
                        scanf("%d",&mat1[R1][C2]);
                }
        }
        printf("Enter 2nd matrix(%dX%d) :",R2,C2);
        for(i=0;i<R2;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<C2;j++)
                {
                        scanf("%d",&mat1[R1][C2]);
                }
        }
        for(i=0;i<R1;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<C2;j++)
                {
                         mat3[i][j]=0;
                        for(k=0;k<C1;k++)
                        {
                                mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("The resultant matrices are :");
        for(i=0;i<R1;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<C2;j++)
                {
                        printf("%5d",mat3[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");

        }
}
```

Comment: Your `scanf()` calls write to memory outside of the bounds of your arrays.

Comment: And your 2nd matrix reading part, you are again rewriting `mat1` contents instead of `mat2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN

> ```
>    for(i=0;i<R1;i++)
>    {
>            for(j=0;j<C1;j++)
>            {
>                    scanf("%d",&mat1[R1][C2]);
>            }
>    }
>    printf("Enter 2nd matrix(%dX%d) :",R2,C2);
>    for(i=0;i<R2;i++)
>    {
>            for(j=0;j<C2;j++)
>            {
>                    scanf("%d",&mat1[R1][C2]);
>            }
>    }
> ```

you do not set the indexes and matrix you want, must be

```
    for(i=0;i<R1;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<C1;j++)
            {
                    scanf("%d",&mat1[i][j]); /* correct indexes */
            }
    }
    printf("Enter 2nd matrix(%dX%d) :",R2,C2);
    for(i=0;i<R2;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<C2;j++)
            {
                    scanf("%d",&mat2[i][j]); /* correct matrix and indexes */
            }
    }
```

I also encourage you to verify your *scanf* returns 1 to check the use enter valid inputs

Comment: Yes, now its working fine..Thank You so much for your help